# Как синхронизировать 1с8x с OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

Ребята подскажите **понятный и проверенный плагин** для синхронизации 1с v.8x (УТП) с OpenCart (пока версию не выбрали - возможно будет 2.3.0.2 или 3.0.3.6 - все будт зависить от плагина). Основная функция плагина должна быть - **ежедневная автоматическая синхронизация с 1С** (без ручной выгрузки/загрузки c 1С). Платная версия тоже рассматривается.
Смотрел в инете пару плагинов по синхронизации, но хотелось бы уже проверенный вариант.